# Autodesk forge - show customized text on markup

Tags: autodesk-forge

We are using markup api from markupcore.js at the moment.

https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/docs/extensions_Markup_core_MarkupsCore.js.html

We want to show customized text on each of the markup drawn on the viewer.

Do you have any apis or ways to do that?

I added into the markup svg string with text, but it reversed as your coordination ways.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the MarkupsCore extension does not support attaching custom labels to markups. You would basically have to manage the labels yourself, adding them as additional text markups or as raw SVG elements (which is exactly what the MarkupsCore code uses under the hood). You would also have to manually sync their position with the markups, for example, using some of the events triggered by the markup tool such as `Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Markups.Core.MarkupsCore#EVENT_MARKUP_SELECTED`
or `Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Markups.Core.MarkupsCore#EVENT_MARKUP_DRAGGING`.